# Set sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the following vba script. 
I want to copy some cells from one sheet to another. 
The first sheet is selected based its name. The sheet where i want to paste the cells is selected based on cell B1 in the first sheet. 
I am using the following code:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet 
Dim LR3 as Long
Dim LR4 as Long
Dim LR5 as Long
Dim ws3 as Worksheet


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "BC-*" Then
    LR3 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("E" & LR3 + 1).Formula = "=SUM(E4:E" & LR3 & ")"


    Dim i As Long, n As Long
       n = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With ws.Range("S1")
            .Formula = "=myJoin(A4:A" & n & ","""")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

    LR4 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("F4:F" & LR4).Copy
    ws.Range("M4:M" & LR4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws.Range("M4:M" & LR4).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    LR5 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("M4:M" & LR4).Cut
    Set ws3 = ws.Range("B1").Value
    ws3.Range("A30").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Range("B1").Value)
```

for example. Adjust the workbook if required.

Comment: Thanks Rory, didn't realize it was that easy :)